# Python - Extract specific lines from tab delimited file based on a value in a column

Tags: python, csv

I am a total newbie, so please bear with me, so far I have only been using the terminal to manipulate csv files via grep and split.

I have a fairly large tab delimited file (500+ MB) that I need to filter based on a criteria in a specific columns. i.e. I would like to select all lines with the value of .error In Header4 and C1 from Header5 andwrite it to a new file:

```
Header1    Header2   Header3  Header4  Header5  Header6
Value1     Value2    Value3   .error   C1       Value6
Value1     Value2    Value3   .Notice  C1       Value6
Value1     Value2    Value3   .error   C2       Value6
Value1     Value2    Value3   .error   C1       Value6
Value1     Value2    Value3   .Main    C2       Value6
```

So based on the example above, the new file would only have the following lines:

```
 Header1    Header2   Header3  Header4  Header5  Header6
 Value1     Value2    Value3   .error   C1       Value6
 Value1     Value2    Value3   .error   C1       Value6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) package.  Pandas is a very powerful data manipulation library. With it, you can do this task with just a few lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table( INPUT_FILENAME ) #read in the file
df = df.query('Header4 == ".error"') #select the rows where Header4 == ".error"
df.to_csv( OUTPUT_FILENAME, sep='\t') #write the output to a tab-separated file
```

INPUT_FILENAME and OUTPUT_FILENAME are strings that provide the path to the input and output files respectively.

If you can't install `pandas`, you could also solve this by reading one line at a time, splitting it on '\t' checking the correct item in the list and then writing only those lines that matched the criteria.

Comment: You can add a second column by adding it to the query: `df.query('Header4 == ".error" & Header5 == "C1"')`

Comment: Thanks - is the INPUT_FILENAME a complete path or just a filename, assuming the script.py and the file_in.txt are in the same directory? I am getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./p2.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_table( file_in.txt ) #read in the file
NameError: name 'file_in' is not defined

Comment: So I was able to figure out the path to the file and I can import the CSV, however the next line - filtering based on the Column "Header4" does not work. I get an error: pandas.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'Header4' is not defined, yet when I do just df command, I can see Header4 being listed with sample values and the total count is correct: [1410065 rows x 14 columns]

Comment: What is the output from `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: Index([u'Header1                                                      ',
       u'Header2 ', u'Header3', u'Header4         ',
       u'Header5 ', u'Header6         ', u'Header7     ', u'Length']
      dtype='object') so it seems the problems are some additional spaces in some of the headers, I tried to include the exact number of spaces but that did not work. Unfortunately stackoverflows removes the additional spaces int he comments - it looks like there are 6 white spaces in the u'TLD     ' header

Comment: There are two options to fix this. One would be to add `delim_whitespace=True` to the `read_table()` call. This would cause it to consume all of the whitespace between columns, but will cause problems if you have non-tab whitespace that is supposed to be part of your data. The other option is to add the command `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` before the `query()` which will clean up any extraneous whitespace around the column designations.

Answer (score 1):

use `csv` module.

```
import csv
output = []
with open('<your_csv_file_to_read>', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in spamreader:
        if 'Header1' in row or row[3] == '.error':
            output.append(row)
with open('<your_csv_file_to_write>', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in output:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

**EDIT**

To make it more performance-efficient, we can open both files at same time and then we don't need to store filtered rows in `output` variable.

```
import csv
output = []
with open('<your_csv_file_to_read>', 'rb') as csvfile1, open('<your_csv_file_to_write>', 'wb') as csvfile2:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter='\t')
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile2, delimiter='\t')
    for row in spamreader:
        if 'Header1' in row or row[3] == '.error':
            spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! You answered while I was editing, I am sorry - how do I include the 2nd parameter i.e. Header5?

Comment: what do you mean by include 2nd parameter ?  Do you mean you want to add filter of 2 columns ? you can do it by changing `if` condition line to `if 'Header1' in row or (row[3] == '.error' and row[4] == 'value5') :`